# validateDOMNesting warning with a <tr>-based component using Enzyme.mount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a component with a `<tr>` as the base element and it renders fine. But when I try to test it using `mount`, I get a warning:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.`

Here's a reproduction:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';

class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>moo</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

it('should not fail', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Foo />);
  console.log(wrapper.html());

});
```

In the call to `mount`, I can wrap the component with `<table><tbody><Foo /></tbody></table>` to make the warning go away. But it feels like there should be another way to do it since this warning doesn't happen with `shallow` or in the application itself.

This is with:

- React 16.5.2
- Enzyme 3.7.0

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to use `mount`?  Using `shallow` is recommended whenever possible because it keeps the test focused on ["testing a component as a unit"](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html).  This keeps your unit tests from "indirectly asserting on behavior of child components" and makes testing much easier by avoiding issues like this where you would need to do additional work to set everything up for a full DOM rendering.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I don't recall the details. I think it was specifically to test some of the child component interactions. Either way, I'd still like to know if there is a way of using mount with a tr-based component.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking if there is a way to test a `<tr>`-based component by itself using `mount`.  The answer is no, whatever you pass to `mount` must be ready for a full DOM rendering and a standalone `<tr>` is invalid.  To use `mount` you would need to wrap the `<tr>`-based component in a `<table>` just like how you describe in your question.

Answer (score 4):

here is the way to fix it

```
it('should not fail', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Foo />, {
    attachTo: document.createElement('tbody'),
  });
  console.log(wrapper.html());
});
```